# C++ OOP Abstract Class - Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

I have an `UserAcount` class that has an abstract class `ContBancar`, and other class `Banca` which reads some users from a file (with method `void Banca::citire_conturi()`). When it reads the users, I get an error "Access violation writing location" in `ContBancar` at `void setBal(double bal) { _balanta = bal; }`. Thx for help !

PS : The file has only one line : 1CBS Dragos 0 dragos12! Gzpvia01= .
Also, i want to make a bank account system, with an user class that has an bank account class which inherits 3 types of a bank accounts, and a bank class which reads some users from a file or put them on it.

```
 class UserAccount
{
private:
    std::string _nume, _user, _pass;
    std::string _cod_us;
    std::shared_ptr <ContBancar> _cont; 

public:
    void setUser(std::string user) { _user = user; }
    void setPass(std::string pass) { _pass = pass; }
    void setNume(std::string nume) { _nume = nume; }
    void setCodUs(std::string cod) { _cod_us = cod; }
    void setContBal(double balanta) { (*_cont).setBal(balanta); }
    std::string getUser() const { return _user; }
    std::string getPass() const { return _pass; }
    std::string getNume() const { return _nume; }
    std::string getCodUs() const { return _cod_us; }
    double getContBal() const { return (*_cont).getBal(); }
    void setContBancar();
};

void UserAccount::setContBancar()
{
    if (_cod_us == "1CBS")
        _cont.reset(new ContBancarSilver());
    else if (_cod_us == "2CBG")
        _cont.reset(new ContBancarGold());
    else
        _cont.reset(new ContBancarDiamond());
}


class ContBancar
{
protected:
    double _balanta;

public:
    void setBal(double bal) { _balanta = bal; }
    double getBal() { return _balanta; }
    virtual bool depozitare(unsigned int) = 0;
    virtual bool retragere(unsigned int) = 0;
};


class Banca
{
private:
    std::vector<UserAccount> vec;
public:
    void citire_conturi();
};

void Banca::citire_conturi()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("Baza_Date.txt");

    UserAccount temp;
    std::string cod, nume, user, pass;
    double balanta;

    while (file >> cod >> nume >> balanta >> user >> pass)
    {
        temp.setCodUs(cod);
        temp.setNume(nume);
        temp.setContBal(balanta);
        temp.setUser(user);
        temp.setPass(pass);
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

    file.close();
}


class ContBancarSilver : public ContBancar
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned int max_balanta = 5000;
    static constexpr unsigned int max_depozitare = 2500;
    static constexpr unsigned int max_retragere = 1000;
    static constexpr double tax_retragere = 0.08;
    static constexpr double bonus_depunere = 0.03;
    static constexpr double bonus_tax_retragere = 0.05;
    static constexpr unsigned int max_depozitari = 1;
    static constexpr unsigned int max_retrageri = 1;

public:
    virtual bool depozitare(unsigned int) override;
    virtual bool retragere(unsigned int) override;
};
```

Comment: `_cont` is never initialized so it contains `nullptr`! So `setContBal` invokes undefined behavior. Where is classes inheriting `ContBancar` and implementing abstractions?

Comment: BTW: always code in English, so everyone could read and understand your code.

Comment: I don't think you need to code in english. It might be easier to get help, but I don't really think it matters.

Comment: You probably want ro read some more about how to use `shared_ptr`, and what its purpose is. For instance, why do you want to share the `ContBancar`, and with whom?

Comment: @floomby very bad advice. Sooner he will start code in English then better. Even crippled version of English will be better. If you learn to use your native language then it will be hard to switch to English later. You can divide your salary by 2 or 3 if you prefer to code in your native language.

Comment: i want to make a bank account system,  with an user class that has an bank account class which inherits 3 types of a bank accounts, and a bank class which reads some users from a file or put them on it

Comment: i m not good at English and i want to be better, but right now it s easy for me to write the code on my native language, and also I've started to learn c++ 2 months ago , and it's quite hard ).

Comment: Now `UserAccount::setContBancar` is never called so you're still de-referencing using `nullptr`.

Comment: My English was much worse than yours when I started coding. Trust me avoid native language, especially if you're planning career in this industry.

Comment: @MarekR how can I initialize ```_cont```? I've tried with an constructor in user class, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on available informationyou should fix your code like this:

```cpp
class UserAccount
{
    .....
    void setCodUs(std::string cod) {
        _cod_us = cod;
        setContBancar();
    }
    void setContBal(double balanta) {
        if (!_cont) setContBancar(); // lazy initialization
        _cont->setBal(balanta);
    }
    ...
};

void UserAccount::setContBancar()
{
    if (_cod_us == "1CBS")
        _cont = std::make_shared<ContBancarSilver>();
    else if (_cod_us == "2CBG")
        _cont = std::make_shared<ContBancarGold>();
    else
        _cont = std::make_shared<ContBancarDiamond>();
}
```

Note I do not understand what kind of logic you are implementing. This changes just ensured that `_cont`  is initialized and up to date with `_cod_us`.

Please stop use explicitly `new` and `delete`. Everything can be created by `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` and containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: ```void UserAccount::setContBancar()``` with this function I want that my users use the methods from their bank account type( if Ana has a ContBancarSilver, she has different members values like taxes, etc,  and this results in overriding methods). Makes sense or?

Comment: I don't understand why you use that "lazy initialization"

Comment: it is design pattern: do not initialize until it is used.